# How to use cygwin

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin

This is a probably a dumb question. I was previously a mac user that uses terminal for everything, now I'm new to windows and tried to use cygwin to get the terminal functionalities. But I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it:

```
$ pwd
/home/rachel

$ ls 
[no output]

$ cd Desktop
-bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong with my cygwin and how could I change directories with it? (`cd Desktop` works on commandline powershell so the path should be fine). Or is there better linux environment simulator for windows?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ls` has no output because there is nothing in your home directory. "Desktop" is not in the cygwin directory tree. Can reach it via: `cd /cygdrive/c/Users/<username>/Desktop/`

Comment: Thank you! How could I go to bashrc and change my default path then? I tried to use that path to access ```.bashrc``` but coudn't get it

Comment: Actually, I was glossing over details. `.bashrc` is a hidden file and doesn't show with `ls` unless `ls -a` is used. The file should be in `/home/rachel/.bashrc`

Comment: ok so ```.bashrc``` does show up with ```ls -a```, but ```cd .bashrc``` gives the ```.bashrc: Not a directory``` error : (

Comment: `.bashrc` is a file not a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin doesn't use your Windows home directory as `/home/rachel` but creates its own directory structure somewhere and translates between UNIX style Cygwin paths and Windows paths. `/home/rachel` may be correspond to `C:\cygwin\home\rachel` or similar.

You can use

```
cygpath -w $(pwd)
```

to see the translation of the current directory.

To get to your Windows drive `C:\` you can use

```
cd /cygdrive/c
```

If your Windows user name is `rachel`, your Windows Desktop is probably

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/rachel/Desktop
```

If `ls -a "$HOME"` doesn't show a `.bashrc`, then this file does not exist yet. Simply create it if you want to use it.

---

An alternative to Cygwin is MSYS2.

https://www.msys2.org/wiki/How-does-MSYS2-differ-from-Cygwin/